# loading image using anglularjs and ibm bluemix

Tags: angularjs, node.js, image, ibm-cloud

I developed an application using nodes and angularjs.
I have an html file that I should display an image.
when running the application on localhost, everything work perfectly and the application displays the image.

I used this code for displaying image:

```
 <img ng-src="./app/images/{{idimage}}.jpeg"  ></img>
```

when I do a push for this application to ibmbluemix, the console told me that there are a 404 not found error.

Any idea please for how displaying image using angulars in ibm bluemix.

Thanks for helps

Comment: check image source after rendering in developer tool of browser,  there is a possibility of incorrect url or "idimage" is not having any value

Comment: Can you please add some more info to your question about how you are pushin your app?  What is the `cf push` command you are using?  What do you have in your manifest?  What does your directory tree look like?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this issue is if you are pushing the app from outside of the app folder by using the manifest path parameter, and when you run your app locally, you also run it from outside the app folder.

After pushing your app, use `cf ssh` ([docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#ssh-command)) to get inside your deployed app.  You can then take a look around using linux tools like `ls` to see what folders have been deployed.